# How to combine a datetime column and an int column into a datetime column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

How to combine a `datetime` column and an `int` column into a single datetime column?

```
DateTime                  TimeInt
--------------------------------------
2017-09-04 00:00:00.000   1409858857
```

Combine both into `datetime` with hour, minute and second

Comment: what is the goal of your query? add seconds, days, hours?

Comment: What is the int (what does it represent)? Why are the currently not in the same column? What database provider are you using? Are you trying to keep the datetime or the int? Do you want to modify the schema or use this in an output query?

Comment: so the asumption is correct, you want to add miliseconds?

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS (Sql-server, oracle, db2, sybase, access, etc).

Comment: Combine how?  What should the result of combing your example be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that INT is a milliseconds which is 17 days, 7 hours, 37 minutes, 38 seconds...

```
declare @table table (dt datetime, i int)
insert into @table
values
('2017-09-04 00:00:00',1409858857)

select
    dt + dateadd(millisecond,1409858857,0)
from
    @table
```

Comment: And also assuming that its Sql Server as opposed to Access / Mysql / DB2 / etc.

Comment: true @Igor I was going off the tsql tag not being Sybase. I didn't know tsql could be used in Mysql.